# Magento show dropdown menus in the admin dashboard from custom module?

Tags: magento-1.7, module, adminhtml, configuration

I am just a newbie to magento. I want to add two menus in the top menu section of admin dashboard.
The menu will be like this

```
Storeinfo(parent)
  Store1(child menu level1/dropdown1)
  Store2(child menu level2/dropdown2)
```

So that when I will make hover on Storeinfo menu it should show Store1 and Store2 as dropdown.
For that my config.xml file is like this

```
<adminhtml>
  <menu>
    <storeinfo module="storeinfo">
      <title>Storeinfo</title>
      <sort_order>71</sort_order>
      <children>
        <items module="storeinfo">
          <title>Store1</title>
          <sort_order>1</sort_order>
          <action>storelocator/adminhtml_storeinfo</action>
        </items>
        <items module="storeinfo">
          <title>Store2</title>
          <sort_order>0</sort_order>
        </items>            
      </children>
    </storeinfo>
  </menu>
</adminhtml>
```

But here with this code I can see only Store2 from the dropdown. So I want to know how can I show two dropdown menus? Any help and suggestions will be really appreciable. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rename your second menu tag into something else.
I mean rename this:

```
<items module="storeinfo">
   <title>Store2</title>
   <sort_order>0</sort_order>
</items>
```

To

```
<items1 module="storeinfo">
   <title>Store2</title>
   <sort_order>0</sort_order>
</items1>
```

A menu tag must be unique in the xml structure. Adding a second item with the same name causes the first one to be overwritten.
**[EDIT]**
If your initial xml worked but was showing only one submenu this should show you the full menu:

```
<adminhtml>
  <menu>
    <storeinfo module="storeinfo">
      <title>Storeinfo</title>
      <sort_order>71</sort_order>
      <children>
        <items module="storeinfo">
          <title>Store1</title>
          <sort_order>1</sort_order>
          <action>storelocator/adminhtml_storeinfo</action>
        </items>
        <items1 module="storeinfo">
          <title>Store2</title>
          <sort_order>0</sort_order>
        </items1>            
      </children>
    </storeinfo>
  </menu>
</adminhtml>
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, I have updated my question kindly check it.

Comment: @NewUser. I've updated the answer

Comment: when I made like your code then the main menu (`Storeinfo`) is disappearing now.

Comment: @NewUser I've added the full xml. Check now.